# Storyline Javascript overide default report.html

Tags: javascript, articulate-storyline

looking to override the default location of the "print report" button in storyline - by default it directs to report.html a canned page that can retrieve the score and test results variables from the completed test - I would like to have the same results sent to report.php so I can work with results on the server side. story.js file looks like:

```
 function onBWEventInterval()
...

case "BW_PrintResults":
 g_oPrintOptions.bShowUserScore = (arrArgs[0] == "true");
 g_oPrintOptions.bShowPassingScore = (arrArgs[1] == "true");
 g_oPrintOptions.bShowShowPassFail = (arrArgs[2] == "true");
 g_oPrintOptions.bShowQuizReview = (arrArgs[3] == "true");
 g_oPrintOptions.strName = arrArgs[4];
 g_oPrintOptions.strMainQuizId = arrArgs[5];
 g_oPrintOptions.arrQuizzes = arrArgs[6].split(",");

 window.open(GetBasePath() + g_strContentFolder + "/report.html", "Reports") 
 break;
```

If I change the /report.html to /report.php this resolves the issue, however I want to leave the story.js file alone as its re-created with every project change.

there is a user.js file that loads after the story.js and is empty, I'm not sure how to override the function / location in the story.js file.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your objective is - I can't seem to follow the question to understand what you're asking.  Are you asking how to change a URL in the page?  If so, please show the relevant HTML and describe which element you want to make the change on.

Comment: I'm asking how to override the default page name in a different javascript file `window.open(GetBasePath() + g_strContentFolder + "/report.html", "Reports") ` needs to be `window.open(GetBasePath() + g_strContentFolder + "/report.php", "Reports") `

Comment: in other words I need a new js file that will override the one line in story.js

Comment: Javascript files don't generally "override" a line of code in another file.  If you make the story.js code more customizable, then something in user.js can cause a change. Do you have the ability to change story.js? For example, story.js could set the location into a variable and then use the contents of that variable in it's `window.open()` command.Then, when user.js loads, it could change the default value of that variable. But, this "hacking" with global variables is rarely the right way to structure your code. I'd have to understand more about the situation to know a better recommendation.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid changing the story.js file at all - it is re-created everytime a project is deployed and needs to remain unchanged - there is a user.js file used for running js changes and additions - I'm just not sure how to override an existing function or add a class.

Comment: It is possible to make a single story.js file that works for all your projects that is overridable by user.js, but in the current story.js, you cannot override a single line of code.  Javascript just doesn't work that way.  story.js is not written to be customizable in that way.  If you can change it once for all your projects, then we can make it customizable by user.js where its default implementation still works the same, but when user.js is present the behavior is altered.  Can you change the one imlementation of story.js to make it customizable?  If so, I will show you how.

Comment: like I said the story.js is not customizable since it get re-written every time a project is edited or changed - what if my user.js is identical to story.js with the small change I need - since it gets loaded after story.js - won't it replace the existing behavior of story.js?

Comment: You can place a copy of the one function in user.js and edit it.  The later definition of the same function will have precedence. But, this is a very bad practice, because of story.js is updated with a different implementation, then your code may break. Having multiple copies of almost the same code is not recommended as it creates maintenance issue. it is better to restructure the code to be customizable so there are not two copies of basically the same code in use. I was suggesting you change the way that story.js is regenerated. Likely, it comes from a template somewhere that can be edited.

Comment: unfortunately the story.js is dynamically created by the project and I don't have the luxury of changing it - the function I'm referring to however doesn't change - I'll try just adding the one function with the changes and see if that works - anything else I would need to add besides the function?